# How to understand other's code, or reverse engineering or whatever it's called

Tags: c#

i was unsure to post this since this can be seen as an useless question, but as i stated before, im newbie at programming and i'm actually reading other's code to improve, since i learn by example, but i downloaded one which does what i exactly need to do, but i don't understand it at all :P.

It's written in c# and i'm using visual studio, could you guys please give me some tips of how to track the flow of the code or something like that using visual studio?, i'm not asking "hey pls explain me this code" but just some tips to understand a code,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the debugger and run in debugging mode, then you can observe the control flow and how different variables change as the program executes, and you can continue execution when you have understood the changes !

Answer (score 1):

According to wiki

> Reverse engineering is the process of discovering the technological principles of a device, object, or system through analysis of its structure, function, and operation.[1] It often involves disassembling something (a mechanical device, electronic component, computer program, or biological, chemical, or organic matter) and analyzing its components and workings in detail—for either purposes of maintenance or to support creation of a new device or program that does the same thing, without using or simply duplicating (without understanding) the original.

I'm pretty sure that what are you trying to do is not reversing engineering.  :)
Long answer short: Use the debugger